# iOS - How to open a part of a page in a UIWebView ?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I want to display in UIWebView a part of this page - https://focus.kontur.ru/search?query=finance

Block to download: div class="block search-block">...

[screenshot of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfG1Z.png)

How can I do that?

Now I do this as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

let url = URL(string: "https://focus.kontur.ru/search?query=finance")
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(url: url!)
webView.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest)
```

Comment: you need to display a portion of the URL?

Comment: There's no easy way to limit `UIWebView` to a particular `<div ... >` Either you should extract the relevant `div` yourself and prepare a light-weight page yourself based on the response. Or do some javascript post processing.

Comment: Or as a yet another alternative you could have a locally prepared `css` applied on the loaded html that would hide the content that you want not to be displayed leaving only the desired `div` visible.

Comment: @Kamil.S Thanks for answers! They are very useful for me.